# Blocking a Jenkins job until a web service returns an HTTP 200?

Tags: hudson, jenkins, hudson-plugins

Is there a way to block a jenkins job until a given webservice returns `HTTP 200` for a given URL? I have a server deployment job with downstream tasks, and it takes a variable length of time to redeploy the application.

I guess I could script something, but an existing plugin or capability would feel like less of a hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write a groovy script to shell out to wget and check the output.